# Issue with CTE (with..as construction)

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I am trying to learn CTE constructions with online excercises.

Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
with mr as 
(
     select min(ram) 
     from pc
)
select model 
from pc 
where ram = mr 
  and speed = (select max(speed) from pc where ram = mr)
```

It fails with error:

> No column name was specified for column 1 of 'mr'

I tried to solve the problem by adding an alias to aggregate column

```
with mr as 
(
    select min(ram) as v 
    from pc
) 
select model 
from pc 
where ram = mr.v 
  and speed = (select max(speed) from pc where ram = mr.v)
```

Now it fails with

> The multi-part identifier "mr.v" could not be bound

So why the queries above produce errors and- what is a right way to write such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mr` is not a column, but a table-like query and you must refer to it as such:

```
with mr as (select min(ram) minram from pc) 
select model from pc 
where ram=(select minram from mr) 
and speed=(select max(speed) from pc where ram = (select minram from mr))
```

Comment: Yeah, I see. Then in this case using CTEs doesn't decrease verbosity much. I thought we can put aggregate value into variable and then reuse it.

Comment: You can use a variable. But in this simple case I don't think that there's too much verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shorter query, then assuming that you want one row, then use `order by` and some form of limit:

```
select pc.*
from pc
order by ram desc, speed asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to tackle this would be to define both of your subqueries as CTEs.

```
with mr as (select min(ram) min_ram from pc),
     ms as (select max(speed) as max_speed from pc where ram = (select minram from mr))

select pc.model 
from pc
    left join mr on pc.ram = mr.min_ram
    left join ms on pc.speed = ms.max_speed
```